# Can a domain name be an alias of a page of a website hosted on a web hoster?

Tags: dns, webserver, alias, web-hosting

Let's say my wordpress website is **example.com**. I want to create an event named *momentum* and I created a page for it at *example.com/events/momentum*. The thing is that momentum is a really important event and I want it to have its own domain name like **momentum.com** but I don't know how to give an alias to the page example.com/events/momentum.
I could do this locally because I had access to my apache web server but, now, I don't. I just have access to cPanel and a limited ssh access.
Can it be done in the DNS configuration or in the redirection definition or somewhere else? Or can I have access to the specific page in the WordPress directory? Or is it just impossible and I have to create a new website if I want to do this ?

Comment: *"I could do this locally because I had access to my Apache web server but now, I don't."* -- This cannot be done with DNS. It sounds like your best bet is to learn how to do this kind of redirect in WordPress,

Comment: Okay, I'm going to check it